# Leaflet with custom map (CRS) - how to convert JPG to TileLayer tiles

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, tile-layer

I have a JPG file with a map which isn't in a real scale, and can't be represented by real geographical latitude and longitude, so I so the Leaflet CRS solution and this seems like the way to go.

The problem is that the map file (JPG) size is ~30MB and can't be loaded in a single request, so I read a bit more and found the TileLayer solution.
I even found a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davido/r2ms3dnp/) .

Now, my only problem is how can I take the JPG file and convert it to layers? Is there an online / offline tool for that?
As far as I understand, all I need is to split the large image to 256px x 256px tiles, place it in directories in my server and TileLayer will do the rest?

Comment: Let's see if this helps clarify : It's NOT a "map". It's a high resolution JPG image that we want to deploy using leaflet, with the same pan and zoom features as slippy maps have, and where rather than making the user load one very large image onto the browser they can progressively load small tiles, at different zoom levels. I'm having the same requirement. The demo link seems to have achieved it, if only they shared how. Hope we find an answer together. @Rotem pls correct if I'm wrong in understanding the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm looking for a similar solution. Sharing what all I've found from a web search. Yet to implement, but check them out and have a go. I searched on duckduckgo for "cut image into tiles for leaflet"

Found:

http://blog.mastermaps.com/2013/06/showing-zoomify-images-with-leaflet.html

Showing Zoomify images with Leaflet - by Bjørn Sandvik. 
It'll be best to take the code from one of his examples and adapt it.
And he's using this:
http://www.zoomify.com/free.htm
He's made a leaflet plugin to enable using tileset prepared by Zoomify:
https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Zoomify

Then, more stuff:

http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#non-map-base-layers
leaflet plugins for non-maps
This lists the zoomify plugin mentioned above, and more options too:

https://github.com/alfarisi/leaflet-deepzoom
leaflet plugin for Deepzoom images.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24819
Deep Zoom composer : windows app for generating tiles

This plugin seems to have the most complete solution, with a shell and python script to generate the image tiles:
https://github.com/commenthol/leaflet-rastercoords

It uses a script, "gdal2tiles.py" to generate the tiles.
https://github.com/commenthol/gdal2tiles-leaflet
Usage example: command for an image whose larger dimension is 3000px:

`python ./gdal2tiles.py -l -p raster -z 0-4 -w none karta.jpg tiles`

there's a shell command for calculating the zoom extents (0-4 or 0-3 etc):

`$ echo "l(3000/256)/l(2)" | bc -l`

---

Update: An article/walkthrough where the author has tiled a very large image successfully and has a demo to show of it: 
https://medium.com/@jarednielsen/how-to-make-an-interactive-story-map-using-leaflet-and-non-geographical-images-821f49ff3b0d

Comment: That was extremely helpful! I've used gdal2tiles. The result of the zoom calculation was 5.9.. so I changed 0-4 to 0-6, but I'm receiving 404 on paths like "2/3/-1", "2/2/-1", "4/-1/4", why is that? where did I go wrong? what is this -1? is it something on my JS declaration?

Comment: ah, possibly the author of that code may not have tested for 6 levels. I suggest you file this as an issue on https://github.com/commenthol/gdal2tiles-leaflet

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2981 - Here's the solution to the -1 and 404 pages issue :)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that libvips can also generate what is expected.

`vips dzsave input.jpg output.zip --layout google`

See:

http://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely understand what are you attempting, to split image on tiles? For do that, You need to register your image at first (e.g. raster - georeferencer in QGIS), so you will assign real geographical latitude and longitude to your image (in projection's or lat\lon coordinates). After this step you will be able to make tiles (tileset) for your image - via gdal2tiles or Qtiles plugin

Comment: But how can I register coordinates if it is a CRS and not a real world coordinates? What am I missing here?

Comment: CRS = Coordinate Reference System, what coordinates? Maybe this helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WYiCUOpt8Q

Comment: one more idea https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/166933/90384

Comment: I actually already ran into that YouTube video, but it shows how to use a layer on a real world map. Maybe I need some clarification on that, if my map isn't in a real world scale, how can I use the method from the YouTube video?

Comment: What is your map represents? Can it be georeferenced somehow or your map is just a picture

Comment: It is an illustrated map which isn't in a real scale.

Comment: Please see the demo jsfiddle linked in the question to get a better idea. That artwork piece wasn't georeferenced.